# How to logout from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, logout

I just created my account at Stack Overflow and now I am unable to logout.

Where is the link to logout or should I clear my cookies?

Comment: I wouldn't be embarrassed.  I've used SO for some time, and just now could not figure it out.  Your question came up in my searching for an answer.

Answer (score 18):

Click on *Stack Exchange* on the top bar **at the right**, then select *log out* from the dropdown.

Comment: Thanks! Found it. It seems even logging out is a geek thing :)

Comment: I have to admit, that is some of the worst UX i have ever seen created for a site.

Comment: Can you attach an image, please?

Comment: Doesn't work in 2019 - got even worse :(

Answer (score 5):

Under the Stack Exchange menu **at the top right side** - there is a log out option (at the top).

Comment: you can log out...but you can never leave

Comment: 2019 - no Stack Exchange menu. It just got even worse :(