# How do you logout of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, logout

This seems embarassing, but I logged in and cannot log out.

I've tried clicking my user account, also tried the Stackoverflow button top left. None of those routes have a clear log out option.

I then examined all the previous answers I can find tagged with log out: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logout.

These all point to a Stackexchange related logout button which doesn't exist. Example: [How to logout from Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258387/how-to-logout-from-stack-overflow)

Short of deleting my Google cookies and restarting Chrome, how can I log out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log out from Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254109/how-can-i-log-out-from-stack-overflow) The first one references the same hamburger menu the answer below shows.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364325).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, this is how you log out!

[image]

Comment: What a STUPID place to hide the damn link! Seriously, what is wrong with SO's UI designers!!!???